# Get current URL from Tomcat6 server?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm looking for a way to get the current URL from my Tomcat6 with Vaadin7. The URL is: mydomain:8080/MyProject.

I'm trying this.

```
public class MyURL {
      public MyURL(){
           System.out.println(VaadinServletService.getCurrentRequest().toString());
           System.out.println(VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().toString());
            System.out.println(VaadinServlet.getCurrent().toString());
      }

}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Check the types returned by `getCurrentRequest` and `getCurrentServletRequest` and check those types' javadoc for the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getLocation()` method of `Page` class.

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation()
```